# Automatic Dependency Generator

Tags: waterfall, dependencies, critical-path

I have  a list of datasets which are required to deliver a large project.  The project is comprised of various products.

Each product has a requirement for one or more of the datasets.

I am want to create an automatic critical path showing which products should go in the most logical order.

I have created a matrix in excel but it is does not generate the work path.  How would I automate such a process?

**TL: DR**

```
- 15 Data Products
require
 - 20 datasets
 - Each product only requires a few of the datasets
 - Some datasets are prequisites for another
 - Calculate the logical order of work
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a scheduling program. List out your data products with subordinate datasets. For each dataset assign an arbitrary duration and appropriate predecessors/pre-requisites, the system should spit out start/end dates that will give you the logical order of work. Example below was done in MS Project, but pretty much any scheduler will be able to accommodate the same logic.

[image]